# print string in the order

Tags: python, python-3.x

the goal is to read a string from the user and put that string in order of the ASCII code without using lists or the sort() Below is my code

```
answer = input("enter string: ")
len_ans = len(answer)
new_answer = ""
previous = " "
leftover =""

while True:
    for i in range(len_ans):

        if (ord(previous[0])) >= (ord(answer[i])):
            new_answer += previous
        else:
            leftover += previous
        print(new_answer)

        previous = answer[i]

    new_answer += leftover
    leftover = ""

    answer = new_answer

    if answer == new_answer:
        print(new_answer)
        break
    else: 
        new_answer = ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You donot need to use ord to compare ASCII-codes for python String.
2. Your sorting algro is not right...and I cannot recognize which algro it belongs to....It looks like a quick sort but not using recursion very well.

And this line in your code is definitely not right,

```
answer = new_answer
if answer == new_answer:
```

Below is one bubble sort example without using list and sort(), hope it helps...

```
answer = 'Hello, world!'

n=len(answer)
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1,i,-1):
        if answer[j]<answer[j-1]:
            answer=answer[:j-1]+answer[j]+answer[j-1]+answer[j+1:]


print(answer)
```

Comment: is this solution called a bubble sort so i may look more into this?

Comment: also, why don't I need to compare ASCII-codes for python String?

Comment: It is one of commonly used sorting alrgro,you can check out the details here. [Bubble sort Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: The compiler will compare the ASCII-codes for you. You only need to write like 'a'>'b', it will return you False. Because  ord('a')=97 and ord('b')=98, but you donot need to write the ord function necessarily.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `sorted` function:

```
>>> s = 'Hello, world!'

>>> sorted(s)
=> [' ', '!', ',', 'H', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'w']   

>>> ''.join(sorted(s))
=> ' !,Hdellloorw'
```

Comment: By the end of the day, one way or another, it will have to be through a sort.

Comment: @AngelValenzuela: There are very many ways to sort a list. Many computer science textbooks have an entire chapter on sorting. But asking for sorting techniques in general is too broad for this site. Is there a particular method of sort that you want to use?

Comment: @RoryDaulton i would preferably like to solve this using string indexing but i don't know how I would go about this. in my code i compare to the previous char

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone what to use it with `chr` and `ord`

```
word = 'Hello, World!'

ords = sorted(ord(x) for x in word)
new_word = ''.join(chr(x) for x in ords)
print(new_word)
```

**Ouput**

```
!,Hdellloorw
```